# How Can I Implement This Function?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner and I want to write Java code in eclipse. This program takes two `LinkedList`s of integers (for example, `a` and `b`) and makes a `LinkedList` (for example `d`) in which every element is the sum of elements from `a` and `b`. However, I can't add these two elements from `a` and `b` because they are Objects

Example:

```
a=[3,4,6,7,8]
b=[4,3,7,5,3,2,1]
------
d=[7,7,13,12,11,2,1]
```

Comment: Post the code of what you have so far so we can better point out what's wrong.

Comment: How are you trying to add the values from the List? Some code would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use generics to tell the compiler that there are integers in the lists

```
List<Integer> a = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

Comment: How is this called, when you write something like `List myList = new LinkedList();` or `List myList = new ArrayList();` or `Map myMap = new HashMap();`?

Answer (score 12):

I'm assuming you're defining the LinkedLists as:

```
LinkedList a, b;
```

in which case `a.get()` will return an `Object`. Java supports [**generics**](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html), which allow you to do:

```
LinkedList<Integer> a, b;
```

Now `a.get()` will return an `Integer` instead of an `Object`. You can tell `LinkedList` is generic because the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) header shows "`Class LinkedList<E>`" -- the `E` is a generic type. The definition of [`get()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#get(int)) is `public E get(int index)` -- since its return type is `E`, whatever you specified for the LinkedList's generic type will be the type returned by that method.

Similarly, the [`add()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add(E)) method's signature is `public boolean add(E o)`, so it will only accept Integers as arguments, and will fail at compile time if you try to add the wrong type.

```
// This is fine
LinkedList a;
a.add(1);
a.add("foo");

// This will fail
LinkedList<Integer> a;
a.add("foo");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change the type of list you are using, Google the words java typecast.

If you do have control over the type of list, use generics as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Is this homework? If so, I won't give you ready-made code, but will point you in the right direction.

To create a List in Java, you would do something like this:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

You would then add elements to the list by calling `list.add(Integer)`

Then, you can iterate through the `List` like so:

```
Integer sum = new Integer(0);
for(Integer i : list)
{
    sum+=i;
}
```

Put these together and add another list and you have your answer...

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing this is homework. I will give you some code but I hope you will learn from this instead of copying and pasting... People seem to think this is wrong but in my book if you are not smart enough to learn from ready code and simply copy and paste, in the end it will show you have learnt nothing.

When i was starting out i loved to have the answers to problems i was facing after i tried them on my own. I learnt a lot, i hope you will too.

The solution is basically, as other people have said, to declare your list as a Generic Integer list:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * @author Savvas Dalkitsis
 */
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> one = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {3,4,6,7,8});
        List<Integer> two = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {4,3,7,5,3,2,1});
        List<Integer> add = addLists(one, two);
        printList(one);
        printList(two);
        printList(add);
    }

    public static List<Integer> addLists(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
        List<Integer> r = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Iterator<Integer> it = a.iterator();
        for (Integer i: b) {
            r.add(i+(it.hasNext()?it.next():0));
        }
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            r.add(it.next());
        }
        return r;
    }

    public static void printList(List<?> list) {
        for (Object o : list) {
            System.out.print(o.toString()+" , ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: do you know something? you are UNIQUE! a thousand times thank you

Comment: and the vote down is from someone who thought that i should not provide the answer? You could post the reason for the vote down you know...

Answer (score 1):

I think you problems are:

if the reference to the objects you are trying to compute are of class Object then yes you have a problem, you need to cast them to Integer:

```
Object o1=object1FromTheList;
Integer integer1=(Integer)o1;

Object o2=object2FromTheList;
Integer integer2=(Integer)o2;
```

Now if your problem is to compute values from them like(you get compilation error):

```
int sum=integer1+integer2;
```

this means your compiler is of older version then 1.5 which does not support auto-boxing, and auto-unboxing:

auto-boxing allows simple code implementation for converting:

**Integer** -> primitive **int**

**Long** -> primitive **long**

...

..

so on like this!

highlights:

without auto-boxing you would have to write:

```
Integer five=new Integer(5); // very annoying to write this as it is isn't it
```

auto-boxing allows you to write it like this:

```
Integer five=5; // nicer shorter and easy to understand
```

without auto-unboxing you would need to write:

```
Integer six=new Integer(6); // no auto-boxing
int _six=six.getValue(); // no auto-unboxing if you have to do some computation this could be hell
```

auto-unboxing allows you to write it like this:

```
Integer six=6; // with auto-boxing
int _six=six; // with auto-unboxing much nicer
```

hope this helps

Adam.